# EKS to integrate Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Can anybody point me to the workflow that I can direct traffic to my domain through Ingress on EKS?

I have this:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress

metadata:
name: hello-world
labels:
    app: hello-world
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

    spec:
    backend:
        serviceName: hello-world
        servicePort: 80
    rules:
    - host: DOMAIN-I-OWN.com
        http:
        paths:
        - path: /
            backend:
            serviceName: hello-world
            servicePort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service

metadata:
name: hello-world
labels:
    app: hello-world

spec:
ports:
- port: 80
    targetPort: 32000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
selector:
    app: hello-world
```

And able to hit `DOMAIN-I-OWN.com` using minikube

kubectl config use-context minikube
  echo "$(minikube ip) DOMAIN-I-OWN.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

But, I can't find tutorials how to do the same thing on AWS EKS?

I have set up EKS cluster and have 3 nodes running.
And have pods deployed with those Ingress and Service spec.
And let's say I own "DOMAIN-I-OWN.com" through Google domains or GoDaddy.

What would be the next step to set up the DNS?

Do I need ingress controller? Do I need install it separate to make this work?

Any help would be appreciated! Got stuck on this several days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wire up something like https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns to automatically point DNS names to your cluster's published services' IPs.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller. It provides a controller that watches for ingress events from the API server. When it finds ingress resources that satisfy its requirements, it begins the creation of AWS resources(subnets, security groups, elbs).

Answer (score 0):

You can create hosted zone on was route 53 and add the records to Godaddy. If you use https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller. After ingress is setup, you will get a cname add it to your route 53 record